# Is there a way to update pandas.pivot_table without reconstructing it?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a student table that contains `student_id`, `course_id`, and `exam_time` (10k rows). I pivot on `student_id` and `exam_time` to get the number of exams in a session or in a day. I am building a timetabling heuristic that changes the times of the examinations one at a time so I need to update this pivot table a lot of times. A change in one course's examination time affects an average of 50 rows in the original dataframe. Is there a way to update the resulting pivot table without recalculating the whole thing in pandas or should I keep track of the changes on the pivot table myself (i.e. by adding and subtracting 1 to the changed slots)?

Edit: Here's how I construct the pivot table. I added a column of ones to count the numbers by np.sum. I couldn't find another function that works faster.

```
sLength = len(df["student_id"])
df["ones"] = pd.Series(np.ones(sLength))
pivot_table = pd.pivot_table(df, rows = "student_id", cols = "exam_time", values = "ones", aggfunc = np.sum)
```

And for the changes in examination times, I wrote this (assuming `changed_course` is moved from `old_slot` to `new_slot`)

```
affected_students = df[df["course_id"] == changed_course]["student_id"]
pivot_table[old_slot][affected_students] -= 1
pivot_table[new_slot][affected_students] += 1
```

Comment: This is one of those things where you should just try whichever seems easier to code first, and then only do the more difficult way if the simple way is too slow.

Comment: Agreee with @cxrodgers, I would go simple at first and see if that is OK.  10k rows is really not that big.  That said, I'd expect the most efficient way to do this would be to store a pivot table for each exam (then add them all together).  Then if you change one exam, you just subtract the old one and add the new one to the combined pivot table.

Comment: can you post some code?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. @HYRY I added the code for the pivot table. Was that what you were asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code, the idea is update the total pivot table by subtract the pivot table of old rows and add the pivot table of new rows.

So every time you change the data, you call twice `pivot_table()`, and one `add()` and one `sub()`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

### create random data
N = 1000
a = np.random.randint(0, 100, N)
b = np.random.randint(0, 30, N)
c = np.random.randint(0, 10, N)

df = pd.DataFrame({"a":a, "b":b, "c":c})

### calculate pivot sum
res = df.pivot_table(values="c", index="a", columns="b", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)

### create random rows to change
M = 100
row_index = np.unique(np.random.randint(0, N, M))
old_rows = df.iloc[row_index]
M = old_rows.shape[0]
new_rows = pd.DataFrame({"a":np.random.randint(0, 100, M), 
                         "b":np.random.randint(0, 30, M),
                         "c":np.random.randint(0, 10, M)})

### update pivot table
sub_df = old_rows.pivot_table(values="c", index="a", columns="b", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)
add_df = new_rows.pivot_table(values="c", index="a", columns="b", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)
new_res = res.sub(sub_df, fill_value=0).add(add_df, fill_value=0)

### check result
df.iloc[row_index] = new_rows.values
res2 = df.pivot_table(values="c", index="a", columns="b", aggfunc="sum", fill_value=0)
print new_res.astype(int).equals(res2)
```